# Node.js: How to know real filename which matches an internal filename in different case on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

My Node.js program wants to read the contents of the file "test.txt" on a Windows machine. It checks with fs.existsSync() that the file exists and reads its content. But now I want the program instead to give an error or warning if the name of the file on disk is actually "TEST.txt" or any other name which differs in case from the name my program is looking for, e.g. "test.txt".

Is there a straightforward way to figure out that even though existsSync() tells me a file exists, the file on disk has a name which differs in case from the file-name I am using to look for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to get a list of all files in directory and then compare the filename to see if matches as is.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = __dirname;
var filename = 'test.txt';

var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
var exists = files.includes(filename);

// true if file on disk is "test.txt",
// false if file on disk is "TEST.txt" 
console.log(exists);
```

Comment: This may be the best answer, I was just hoping there would be a way to do it without having to read the list of files which can be long then check that list for inclusion. Thanks